# How do you perform a real 'move' operation of a GCS storage object, where real 'move' is one that maintains the Last Modified date?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I move a Google Cloud Storage Object from one bucket to another bucket, or from one "folder" to another "folder" within the same bucket (i.e., a name identity change within the bucket), the Last Modified date is always changed to the date/time of the move.

I would like to move a storage object and have Google Cloud maintain the Last Modified time. If the storage object's contents has not changed, I do not want a move to change the metadata's Last Modified date/time.

I have tried the following tests, but none maintain Modified time:

- gsutil .\File.txt gs://bucket-name1/
- gsutil gs://bucket-name1/File.txt gs://bucket-name1/SameBucketNameChange/
- gsutil gs://bucket-name1/File.txt gs://bucket-name2
- Using the GCS portal/console to manually select File.txt, choose move, select a destination bucket that is different from the first bucket.

In all cases, both the Last Modified and Created times change. I would expect at least the Last Modified time to remain unchanged just as it does in both Windows/Linux when there is a move operation.

Especially with cloud storage objects, I would think a positive value add would be date/time integrity, that at least some date/time would be tied to storage object content changes (without such changes that date/time would not change... usually this would be the Last Modified date/time).

The best option I could find so far is when using a Transfer Job with [metadata preservation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/metadata-preservation) specified for Created time but the result is that GCS still modifies the destination Created/Modified times, but it carries over (copies) the original object's Created time as a new "Custom time" field which seems somewhat odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no Last Modified date in Cloud Storage. Objects cannot be modified therefore there cannot be a date that you modified the object. You can only change an object by creating a new object and copying the data. Even changing the name requires a copy operation.
2. Cloud Storage does not support Move. That is emulated with Copy and Delete.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley! Stemming from your answer, I see mention of immutable nature in docs. Interestingly, there is not parity with at least one other provider who offers mutable forms. For long term archive commitments, where creation date is of importance, it seems best to go single or low cost region since changing regions involves transfer costs, possibly hitting early deletion fees. This is for budget usage, to keep costs down where latency during recovery not important. Thanks again for clarifying immutability! Immutable info: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects

Comment: At the same time `gsutil` uses a kind of a standard metradata `goog-reserved-file-mtime` for storing file's last modified date. And it should be preserved while copying object within the cloud. Even more, it becomes the file's modification time when you copy/sync the object to the local file system.